# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired on Magento cloud cli installation

Tags: macos, ssl, magento, magento2, mamp

I'm working on macOS Retina, Late 2013, I faced issue while installing Magento Cloud Cli.
I followed Magento documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html
[image]

I tried every possible solution, but it didn't work, anybody faced this issue before?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using iterm2 instead of default terminal of the macOS